# ASP.NET Session in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

Session in **Application_AuthenticateRequest** method in Global.asax is always null.Ive already try:

```
this.Session,HttpContext.Current.Session
```

always null.

```
  protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
    {
        string userRole = string.Empty;

        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (this.Session["UserRole"] == null)
            {
               InsertSessionValue();
            }
            userRole =Session["UserRole"].ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, new string[] {userRole});
        }
    }
```

Ive also try to use Cache,but it doesnt work because i need unique information for each user.

How to use Session in Global.asax?Is HttpApplication Application property unique for each user?

Comment: id say its likely you're not calling that method properly. The reason for the NULL occurs when there is no request being processed. How are you calling that method/assigning that delegate?

Comment: Calling Application_AuthenticateRequest?It fires automatically when a user try to authenticate;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just can't use Session at this point in the request lifecycle, it isn't available/populated yet, if you want to use it you'll need to move to an event later in the lifecycle, for example [`PostAcquireRequestState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate.aspx).